# c# assign conditional value to class member

Tags: c#, class

is there any way to assign conditional value to a class member within same class?

```
public class getStudent
{
private bool itsOkay = false;
private short stID = 0;

public bool ValusOkay
    {
        get  {return itsOkay;}
        set  {itsOkay = value;}
    }
 public short STid
    {
        get {return stID;}
        if(itsOkay == true)
           set {stID = 8;}
        else
           set {stID = 0;}
    }    
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just move the if test into the set block.

Comment: Note that you can leave out that `== true`, because `itsOkay` is already a boolean itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

Also to cast from `int` to `short` in ternary operator, the syntax should be like this

```
    public short STid
    {
        get {return stID;}

        set {stID = itsOkay  ? (short)8 : (short) 0;}          
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put anything inside get or set method - `if, for, while .....`, but its not recommended to put a lot of lines of code in property. But in your case you can simply put your `if` inside setter:

```
public short STid
{
    get {return stID;}
    set 
    {
        if(itsOkay == true)
            stID = 8;        
        else
            stID = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code actually shows what you are trying to you don't need a setter at all.

```
public short STid => (itsOkay) ? (short) 8 : (short) 0;
```

This will create a getter returning 8 or 0 depending on the given condition.